# CSC classes missing after TYPO3 upgrade

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

I'm fairly new to TYPO3 and after an update from 6.2 to 7.6, all the CSS styled Content classes have changed to csc-default.

I've included css_styled_content to my template and that gave the site it's overall stylesheet, but it just seems that none of the content itself are given their individual classes e.g. csc-frame-nav, in the HTML typo3 outputs.

Any pointers or help of what to do would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that the HTML class attributes have changed? Or that the `<style>` element is missing from the page? Or something else?

Comment: All the styles in the stylesheet are there, it's just that typo3 isn't applying the classes to the elements :/

Comment: Are you saying that the class attributes are missing from the HTML?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

First thing to trym is include an older version of the static template from `CSS styled content` in your TS template (`include static`).

Also make sure you do not accidentally render your frontend with `Fluid styled template`, which is new in `TYPO3 7 LTS`.